# Error loading an image named by a ltxkey

Tags: includegraphics, key-value

I am new to TeX and LaTeX and my first project is a very ambitious one. The plan is to use `ltxkeys` to define database entries for the D&D Role Playing game, and then have LaTeX templates to pretty-print character sheets, monster stats, etc. I've just begun, and have had some success, but I am running into trouble with this test file:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,landscape]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%Use a modern font encoding
\usepackage[sfdefault]{noto}
\usepackage[margin=.5in,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphbox}% Loads graphicx automagically.
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage[tracingkeys]{ltxkeys}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1in}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1in}

\makeatletter  
% Monster Tent Graphic is 300 DPI with:
% * image size of (600x2250 pixels) 2in x 7.5in
% * monster title of 630x62 pixels (2.1in x .207in)
% Use a Data Key: \DnD{WUMPUS}{image}
\newcommand{\DnD}[2]
  {%
    {%
      \def\c{#1}
      \def\v{#2}
      \def\t {\csname DnD@KeyFam@\c \endcsname}%
      \csname cmd\t @\c @\v \endcsname%
    }%
  }

% Define a Creature Data Key:
% \DnDNewCreature{WUMPUS}{title="Grand Wumpus", image=..."}
\newcommand{\DnD@NewCreature}[2]%
  {%
    \ltxkeys@declarekeys[DnD@Creature]{#1}%
      { cmd/\needvalue{title}//;
        cmd/\needvalue{image}//;
      }%
    \expandafter\def\csname DnD@KeyFam@#1\endcsname{DnD@Creature}%
    \ltxkeys@setkeys[DnD@Creature]{#1}{#2}%
  }

\def\gimg {img/MM167-Goblin-BW.png}
\DnD@NewCreature{GoblinBoss}{title=Goblin Boss,image=img/MM167-Goblin-BW.png}

\begin{document}%
\def\m {GoblinBoss}%
\begin{figure}[t]%
  \begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}%
    % \includegraphics[smash=cc,width=2in,totalheight=2.5in,keepaspectratio,angle=180,hshift=-1.25in,vshift=-2.1in]{\DnD{GoblinBoss}{image}}
    \includegraphics[smash=cc,width=2in,totalheight=2.5in,keepaspectratio,angle=180,hshift=-1.25in,vshift=-2.1in]{img/MM167-Goblin-BW.png}%
    \includegraphics[smash=cr,totalheight=7.5in,width=2.5in]{img/Monster-Tent.png}%
    \begin{textblock}{2.1}(.2,-.42)%
      \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}
        {\centerline{\fontsize{16}{16}\textbf{\DnD{GoblinBoss}{title}}}}  
    \end{textblock}
  \end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
\makeatother
```

As is, the file correctly renders the monster tent image and correctly places the desired image and title, however, this is only because the `\includegraphics` command uses the literal text of the path to the file to load, rather than pulling it out of an `ltxkey`. If the first commented-out `\includegraphics` command is used instead of the second, I get an obscure error from inside includegraphics that there is an `"Illegal parameter number in definition of \filename@base"`.

If, instead of the `ltxkey`, I use `\gimg` which is just defined to be the image file path, it works. If I try to define `\gimg` to be `{\DnD{GoblinBoss}{image}}` enter code here it fails again. If I just print the value of `\DnD{GoblinBoss}{image}` it appears correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the argument to `\includegraphics` has to _expand_ to the filename and your `\DnD` command does not work by expansion it introduces grouping and local assignment such as `\def\c`.  It also introduces a lot of white space from missing `%` at ends of lines. Actually it's not clear why you introduce the assignments since they are discarded at the end of the group why not `\newcommand{\DnD}[2]{\csname cmd\csname DnD@KeyFam@#1\endcsname@#1@#2\endcsname}`

Comment: also any particular reason to use the ltxkeys rather than more standard keyval systems such as keyval or l3keys or pgfkeys?

Comment: beware using one letter commands (or `\def`) as you have it in a group just for filename use `\def\c` or `\def`\t` are sort of OK but in most places such a definition would break latex's text encoding support.

Comment: How do I then define a temporary macro that expands to the results of the \DnD command? As for why to use ltxkeys, I was looking for something that could parse sub-expressions like DnDNewCreature{Fish}{stats={str=10,int=14}}

Comment: doesn't the definition I suggest above work without all the non-expandable grouping and assignment?

Comment: Perhaps, but I'm a sufficient newbie that your answer didn't make any sense to me. After all I'm defining a macro. All it DOES in the end is expand. I still don't see why having a definition, which presumably expands to null, has any effect.

Comment: definitions do not expand, they are not expandable. It is similar to other programming languages, if something is expecting (say) an integer x=2 you can't insert a fragment of code with local assignments `x={a=1;b=1;a+b}`

Comment: Thanks. Clearly I shall need to reread the documentation on how macros are processed. Meanwhile I find that although the correct file name now expands, the includegraphics command cannot find and load the file, although the exact string as a literal, works. Experimentation shows its not recognizing the .png on the end as an extension, and is trying to load foo.png.png, foo.png.jpg, etc. No idea why.

Comment: that could be fixed but simplest is not to supply the extension and let includegraphics add it

Comment: Yes, but as I'm making macros that I hope other folks will eventually use, I would have to pass that admonishment on to the end user. The most flexibility I can achieve in acceptable file names, the better.

Comment: fair enough, I'll look later, won't be hard to adjust that.

Comment: Any other key=value implementation supports sub-expressions, just let your key set other keys in another set (so your `stats` key sets keys in a set `creature-stats` or something like that, for instance with `expkv-def` you could do `code stats = \ekvset{creature-stats}{#1}`). One should avoid using `ltxkeys`, it's no longer compatible with LaTeX anyways, but even before it was problematic.

Comment: Okay, so what would you recommend as the best key=value implementation right now?

Comment: @swestrup tough question. There are (imho) three viable choices: `pgfkeys` (not the most bug free, but wide spread and does allow stuff the other two in this list won't out of the box -- especially recommended if you want to build something in Ti*k*Z/`pgf`). `l3keys` (very robust, clean separated interface, defining in one and setting in another macro). `expkv` (with `expkv-def`; very fast, robust but ugly error messages due to the parser being fully expandable, like `l3keys` defining at one point, setting at another -- I'm the author, so biased).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the command such that it expands to the image filename.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,landscape]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%Use a modern font encoding
\usepackage[sfdefault]{noto}
\usepackage[margin=.5in,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphbox}% Loads graphicx automagically.
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage[tracingkeys]{ltxkeys}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1in}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1in}

\makeatletter  
% Monster Tent Graphic is 300 DPI with:
% * image size of (600x2250 pixels) 2in x 7.5in
% * monster title of 630x62 pixels (2.1in x .207in)
% Use a Data Key: \DnD{WUMPUS}{image}
\newcommand{\badDnD}[2]
  {%
    {%non expandable group start
      \def\c{#1} % non expandable assignment and space token
      \def\v{#2} % non expandable assignment and space token
      \def\t {\csname DnD@KeyFam@\c \endcsname}% non expandable assignment
      \csname cmd\t @\c @\v \endcsname%
    }%non expandable group end
  }
\newcommand{\DnD}[2]{\csname cmd\csname DnD@KeyFam@#1\endcsname @#1@#2\endcsname}

% Define a Creature Data Key:
% \DnDNewCreature{WUMPUS}{title="Grand Wumpus", image=..."}
\newcommand{\DnD@NewCreature}[2]%
  {%
    \ltxkeys@declarekeys[DnD@Creature]{#1}%
      { cmd/\needvalue{title}//;
        cmd/\needvalue{image}//;
      }%
    \expandafter\def\csname DnD@KeyFam@#1\endcsname{DnD@Creature}%
    \ltxkeys@setkeys[DnD@Creature]{#1}{#2}%
  }

\def\gimg {img/MM167-Goblin-BW.png}
\DnD@NewCreature{GoblinBoss}{title=Goblin Boss,image=example-image.png}

\begin{document}%
\def\m {GoblinBoss}%
\begin{figure}[t]%
  \begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}%
     \includegraphics[smash=cc,width=2in,totalheight=2.5in,keepaspectratio,angle=180,hshift=-1.25in,vshift=-2.1in]{\DnD{GoblinBoss}{image}}
    \includegraphics[smash=cc,width=2in,totalheight=2.5in,keepaspectratio,angle=180,hshift=-1.25in,vshift=-2.1in]{example-image-a.png}%
    \includegraphics[smash=cr,totalheight=7.5in,width=2.5in]{example-image-b.png}%
    \begin{textblock}{2.1}(.2,-.42)%
      \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}
        {\centerline{\fontsize{16}{16}\textbf{\DnD{GoblinBoss}{title}}}}  
    \end{textblock}
  \end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
\makeatother this is never executed
```

[image]